# Convert a jagged array to a 2D array directly without iterating each item?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, export-to-excel, jagged-arrays

I am trying to save a DataTable into an excel sheet.. my code is like this..

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2");
range = range.get_Resize(dtExcel.Rows.Count, dtExcel.Columns.Count);
object[,] rng1 = new object[dtExcel.Rows.Count, dtExcel.Columns.Count];
```

Excel range requires range value as array[,] but I have the DataTable as jagged array[][].

```
object[][] rng2 = dtExcel.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Is there any built-in function to directly convert the jagged array[][] to a 2D array[][] ?
Iterating through Excel, DataTable and assigning seems slower with bulk data..

Also I don't want to setup querying with DSN for excel.. I chose excel storage to avoid the configuring of any databases.. :P 
I found a detailed explanation of ways of writing data to excel here..
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/5d525b76-f5b6-4340-a899-c3c82570d2e1 might help

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. the array types are different in my case. but let me try :)

Comment: Got an exception saying 'The specified arrays must have same dimensions.' 
Jagged array size shows as [80][] and array size shows as [80,12]. Jagged array is having 12 items in each row, but still it didn't detect as arrays with same dimensions.

Comment: You might have to iterate through each row and copy them individually. Or if you know each row in the jagged array is the same length (which I think you do), you could try a SelectMany() to flatten it into a 1D array, then copy that to the 2D? Not sure if it'll work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I used [NPOI library](https://github.com/qihangnet/npoi) for this. It is quite simple and free.

The code to convert DataTable to excel as follows.

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        foreach (DataTable dt in DataSource.Tables)
        {
            ISheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.CreateSheet(dt.TableName);

            //Set column titles
            IRow headRow = sheet1.CreateRow(0); 
            for (int colNum = 0; colNum < dt.Columns.Count; colNum++)
            {
                ICell cell = headRow.CreateCell(colNum);
                cell.SetCellValue(dt.Columns[colNum].ColumnName);
            }

            //Set values in cells
            for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= dt.Rows.Count; rowNum++)
            {
                IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(rowNum);
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < dt.Columns.Count; colNum++)
                {
                    ICell cell = row.CreateCell(colNum);
                    cell.SetCellValue(dt.Rows[rowNum - 1][colNum].ToString());
                }
            }

            // Resize column width to show all data
            for (int colNum = 0; colNum < dt.Columns.Count; colNum++)
            {
                sheet1.AutoSizeColumn(colNum);
            }
        }
```