# Smartest way to convert an array of the form [][] to [,]?

Tags: c#, arrays

If you have an array like string[][], what's the smartest way to convert it to a regular multidimensional array like string[,] assuming the former array is rectangular (not jagged)?

The only approach I can think of is to get the dimensions, declare a multidimensional array with those dimensions, then loop through the source array and populate the new array. But I was wondering if there were any simpler solutions.

Comment: What problems do you have with your proposed solution?  In what way is it not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a jagged array to a 2D array directly without iterating each item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438587/convert-a-jagged-array-to-a-2d-array-directly-without-iterating-each-item)

Comment: Also, why do you prefer `[,]` over `[][]`? Usually its the other way around.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Well, a multidimensional array has improved memory locality.  It can be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on the situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jagged arrays <-> multidimensional arrays conversion in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010219/jagged-arrays-multidimensional-arrays-conversion-in-asp-net)

Comment: @BartoszKP The linked question has no relevance the OP as the answer is to some specific problem which does not concern him. It has no use here.

Comment: @BartoszKP He's *not* asking how to do the copy without iterating.  He's asking for the simplest way of doing it, knowing that he has to iterate.  So that's not really a dup.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `Array.CopyTo` and `arr2d.SelectMany(x => x)`? `memcpy` might also be useful since `[,]` is just like a normal `[]` in memory.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Array.CopyTo only works for single dimensional arrays.  `SelectMany` wouldn't create a multidimensional array; it would create a single dimensional array.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but you can then copy the content of that array into the multidimensional one. I wasn't sure if `Array.CopyTo` has an overload for multidimensional or not, but for that he can use `memcpy`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan How is it any easier to copy the data from a single dimensional array to a multidimensional array than to copy it from a jagged array?  Also note that doing two copies instead of one would have *dramatic* performance costs.  Most likely prohibitively so.  As for scrapping managed code and copying the underlying memory directly, you could only do that from a single dimensional array, and that doesn't seem like it would be simpler at all.  It seems quite a bit more complex.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, I want it mainly because I'm tying into existing code that needs [,] as input.

Comment: There is no simpler solution..

Comment: @Servy, I asked this mainly out of curiosity. I've seen some very elegant LINQ-style solutions in the past. While my solution would work, a one-line solution would be nice, but so would any alternative solution that teaches me a new technique.

Comment: @Dalal LINQ, as a rule, doesn't play nice with multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just for fun: totally agree that's an overkill and the very best way is the normal iteration.

```
    //example jagged array
    string[][] ja = new string[2][];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        ja[i] = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(k => "Cell [" + i + "," + k + "]").ToArray();

    //conversion to a 2D-array
    string[,] ka = new[] { new string[ja.Length, ja[0].Length] }
        .Select(_ => new { x = _, y = ja.Select((a, ia) => a.Select((b, ib) => _[ia, ib] = b).Count()).Count() })
        .Select(_ => _.x)
        .First();

    //dump result
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ka[i, k]);
        }
```

Almost unreadable, but it works (at least when the initial array is not empty/malformed).

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for the neat solution. And I agree that perhaps normal iteration is indeed the best solution. Correct answer.